# Disabling all widgets within a DIV using Dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dojo

I have a DIV with multiple widgets inside it like dropdown, buttons, textbox, checkbox, radiobuttons widgets. I would like to disable all the widgets inside the div on button click. Is there a way i could disable the whole div, instead of iterating through each input element, or widget within it. I have tried the following,

```
dojo.query('#container :input').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

This would disable all input elements like textboxes, however the buttons are still clickable. I had to get button id and disable it again. Is this going to be DOM expensive operation?

I have tried using CSS pointer-events property, however this seems to have browser issues.

What would be the robust and efficient way i can achieve this, which makes future enhancements easier, like adding new widgets and input elements to the div

Comment: What's the problem with including button ids in your dojo query selector?

Comment: I am not sure using query on all input elements is going to be expensive dom operation. The problem with using button id, i mean is that in the future if i want to add new button, i have to come back and change code again

Comment: tried using the children attribute of the parent container??

Comment: @nikitha Can you please accept the below answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `dijit` components like `dijit/form/Button`, `dijit/form/TextBox`, then you should be using the `set` function. You can get all the widgets in a div using `registry`.

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (array, dom, registry) {
    var _widgets = registry.findWidgets(dom.byId("fooDiv"))
    array.forEach(_widgets, function(item){
        item.set('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

This is just an illustrative example for you to see the syntax, hope it helps.